# Random float value is repeating

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my code to recreate a random x and y value if there is already another object occupying the chosen value. But for some reason, the loop just keeps giving me the same float value causing it to loop forever instead of creating new value and then checking that one against previous x and y variables. Here's the code. Let me know if you need anymore.

```
static int numberOfDots = 5;
static int windowSize = 400;

float[] pos = new float[2];
float[] vel = new float[2];
float[] acc = new float[2];
float dotSize = 0;
float dotMass = 0;
float dotWidth = 0;
float dotRadius = 0;
float[] centrePos = new float[2];

float[][] dots = new float[numberOfDots][10];

//for making dots
boolean first = true;
boolean creationCollision = false;
boolean dotCollision = false;

// pos means x and y positions
// vel means x and y velocity
// centrePos means centre of the dot x and y
// dotMass isnt implemented yet
    public boolean collisionOnCreate() {
        //compare all dots
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            //against any dots later in the array
            // since they will already have compared themselves to dots previous in the array
            // - dont need to loop over them again
            for (int a = i + 1; a < dots.length; a++) {
                if (dots[a][0] != 0) {
                    creationCollision = dots[i][1] + dots[i][8] > dots[a][1] && dots[i][1] + dots[i][8] < dots[a][1] + dots[a][8] || dots[i][1] > dots[a][1] && dots[i][1] < dots[a][1] + dots[a][8] || dots[i][0] > dots[a][0] && dots[i][0] < dots[a][0] + dots[a][8] || dots[i][0] + dots[i][8] > dots[a][0] && dots[i][0] + dots[i][8] < dots[a][0] + dots[a][8];
                    System.out.println(dots[a][0] + " " + dots[a][1]);
                }
                //check if the left-most part of the dot is anywhere between the leftmost and right most part of another dot
                //check if the rightmost part of the dot is anywhere between the left most and right most part of another dot
                //check if the top part of the dot is anywhere between the top and bottom part of another dot
                //check if the bottom of the dot is anywhere between the top and bottom part of another dot
                // I know its long but its easier then running a bunch of if statements to do the same task    
            }
        }
        return creationCollision;
    }

    public void createDots(int i) {
        pos[0] = r.nextFloat() * 300;
        pos[1] = r.nextFloat() * 300;
        dotWidth = r.nextFloat() * 30;
        if (dotWidth < 5) {
            dotWidth *= 10;
        }
        dotRadius = dotWidth / 2;
        dotMass = r.nextFloat() / 10;
        centrePos[0] = centrePos[0] + dotRadius;
        centrePos[1] = pos[1] + dotRadius;
        vel[0] = r.nextFloat() / 10;
        vel[1] = r.nextFloat() / 10;
        check(i);
    }

    public void check(int i) {
        collisionOnCreate();
        if (creationCollision) {
            createDots(i);
            System.out.println("collision on creation");
        } else {
            setValues(i);
            System.out.println("dot number " + i + " is created");
        }
    }

    public void setValues(int i) {
        dots[i][0] = pos[0];
        dots[i][1] = pos[1];
        dots[i][2] = vel[0];
        dots[i][3] = vel[1];
        dots[i][4] = dotRadius;
        dots[i][5] = centrePos[0];
        dots[i][6] = centrePos[1];
        dots[i][7] = dotMass;
        dots[i][8] = dotWidth;
    }

    //create an array of dots and assign them values for x, y, radius, etc.
    public float[][] Dots() {
        if (first == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDots; i++) {
                    createDots(i);
            }
            first = false;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDots; i++) {
                // update values
                dots[i][0] = dots[i][0] + dots[i][2];
                dots[i][1] = dots[i][1] + dots[i][3];
                centrePos[0] = dots[i][0] + dots[i][4];
                centrePos[1] = dots[i][1] + dots[i][4];
                dots[i][5] = centrePos[0];
                dots[i][6] = centrePos[1];
                collisionOnWall(i);
            }
        }
        repaint();
        return dots;
    }
```

Comment: A good first step would be to [edit] your question to show us some declarations of all those variables.

Comment: floating value is never exact therefore the boolean creationCollision is imprecise and could be wrong.

Comment: To make this more readable, I suggest you use a point class rather than array values for x and y values.

Comment: Any decent random number generator will produce collisions. If it doesn't, it isn't truly random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with random number generation. Instead there is something wrong with the logic of creation / checking.

It seems that first, inside of `createDots()`, you assign values to some variables that are meant to represent a new dot (why don't make a dedicated class for that?). Then you don't add that new dot to `dots` array but instead you go straight to checking if there are any collisions.

However, you only check the values that are already present in the `dots` array, without taking into account the newly created one.

Another thing, that `creationCollision` condition is really unreadable to me. You should use some parentheses just for the clarity. Plus make sure it is actually doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to ever set dots[i] to your new values here:

```
public void createDots(int i) {
    pos[0] = r.nextFloat() * 300;
    pos[1] = r.nextFloat() * 300;
    dotWidth = r.nextFloat() * 30;
    if (dotWidth < 5) {
        dotWidth *= 10;
    }
    dotRadius = dotWidth / 2;
    dotMass = r.nextFloat() / 10;
    centrePos[0] = centrePos[0] + dotRadius;
    centrePos[1] = pos[1] + dotRadius;
    vel[0] = r.nextFloat() / 10;
    vel[1] = r.nextFloat() / 10;
    check(i);
}
```

Looks like you want to call setValues(i) at the end, just before check(i).

Comment: This way the new dot will always be added to the `dots` no matter if there is collision or not. He needs consider that new dot in the check and just then add it.